# c# Skype application send text to current chat on trigger

Tags: c#, winforms, skype, visual-c#-express-2010, skype4com

OK so I am making a Skype tool box program that does many things, but I am having trouble with the Aui.

This part of the program is meant to see commands that are sent in a chat with a person and print text. For example if you say !fatty in a chat with somebody, it would write "yo fat boy".

I discovered this code online :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SKYPE4COMLib; // Our COM library

namespace SkypeBing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Skype skype;
        private const string trigger = "!"; // Say !help
        private const string nick = "Skype Admin";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            skype = new Skype();
            // Use skype protocol version 7 
            skype.Attach(7, false);
            // Listen 
            skype.MessageStatus +=
              new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skype_MessageStatus);
        }
        private void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg,
                     TChatMessageStatus status)
        {
            // Proceed only if the incoming message is a trigger
            if (msg.Body.IndexOf(trigger) == 0)
            {
                // Remove trigger string and make lower case
                string command = msg.Body.Remove(0, trigger.Length).ToLower();

                // Send processed message back to skype chat window
                skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick +
                      " Says: " + ProcessCommand(command));
            }
        }

        private string ProcessCommand(string str)
        {
            string result;
            switch (str)
            {
                case "hello":
                    result = "Hello!";
                    break;
                case "help":
                    result = "Sorry no help available";
                    break;
                case "date":
                    result = "Current Date is: " +
                             DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
                    break;
                case "time":
                    result = "Current Time is: " +
                             DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                    break;
                case "who":
                    result = "It is Praveen, aka NinethSense " +
                             "who wrote this tutorial";
                    break;
                default:
                    result = "Sorry, I do not recognize your command";
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work because it needs to be sent to a user. I am fairly new to this Aui. If anybody has any ideas on methods that I could use to call this event correctly because there is not much support online so I thought I would ask you super people. :D If you need more information or would like to be a part of its development please just ask .

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
 {
       if (msg.Body.Contains("faty"))
       {
            skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle,"Go away fatty!");
       }
  }

skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skype_MessageStatus);
```

Thats a basic outline of what you can do, its easy to expand from there. Hope this clears things up.